# wp_delete_attachment doesn't delete image files / doesn't work

Tags: attachments, media, customization, uploads

[`wp_delete_attachment`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_delete_attachment/) should delete everything that is about attachment.

However if I do

```
wp_delete_attachment( (int)$delete_attachment_id, true );
```

The files remain on the server (even **`true`** should indicate force delete).

**Function *acts* as successful:**

> **Return:** (WP_Post|false|null) Post data on success, false or null on failure.

...it **does** return `WP_Post` object and really the `WP_Post` object of this attachment **is** deleted.

But the files are not deleted... not even the thumbnails...

*Additional info: this happens for files previously added with `media_handle_upload`*

Comment: The function does have unreliable return, I've reported that, but I just noticed that `wp_delete_attachment_files()` also returned true altough file remained... it comes down to `wp_delete_file_from_directory()` which again doesn't check if the deletion really happened and to final `wp_delete_file()` which is the final one and still it just silently calls PHP's unlink and does not check if the file was really deleted or not...

Comment: As to this my case, it was caused by filter `wp_delete_file` which made the filepath empty, therefore the file `wp_delete_file()` could not be successful, but still this part of WP is currently unreliable.